# Why is decltype not allowed on private member variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
  std::vector<int> bar;

public:
  std::vector<int>& get_bar() { return bar; }
};
```

and later on, I want another variable somewhere else that has the same type as `bar`. It would make sense to me if I could just do this:

```
decltype(Foo::bar) clone_of_bar;
```

But that doesn't work. The compiler tells me *'std::vector< int > Foo::bar' is private*.

So I end up having to use something like this:

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<Foo>().get_bar())>::type clone_of_bar;
```

Which works, but looks like a complete mess. Maybe there's an easier way to do it; I'm not really sure. But what I really want to know is why I can't just use `decltype(Foo::bar)`. Why should anyone care that `bar` is private? It's not like I'm actually accessing the variable.

`decltype` is a new feature of the language. I just don't understand why it was designed to not work on private variables.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could give us some **actual** example in which you would benefit from using decltype on private members.

Comment: Well, I have any really solid reasons for wanting to do this. It was mostly just curiosity.  But the case where I tried to use it was this: I was using google protobuf, for which I define some event types and then protobuf generates some code for those types. The generated code looks a bit like what I wrote in my question example. The thing is, I want to be able to copy some of the data out of the protobuf message to do some stuff with and I don't want to have to change the code if I happen to change the type in the protobuf message. So that's what I wanted to do. Not really a big deal though.

Comment: Couldn't you just use "auto x = somefoo.get_bar();" ? You'd be copying, without explicitly providing the type of "x".

Comment: I can't use auto, because the copy is a permanent member of a some class. Basically I've got a class which stores a 'state', and these protobuf message contain new bits and pieces of the the state. So when a protobuf message comes in, I want to get rid of parts of the old state and replace it with the new. -- So anyway, I can't use auto, because I have to declare the type before get_bar can be called.

Comment: +1 I actually have a real example where this is a verifiable PITA.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14934749/975129 I have to use `decltype` due to a variadic function that will return different types depending on which args are passed in.  As an evil consequence, I have to make my `m_map` member public in my `at()` method?!?  Argh!  I may have to use your workaround, but then I would have to add an unnecessary `get` method..

Comment: fwiw, the guy who answered my question came up with a workaround - `decltype(std::declval<std::map<I,child_type>>().at(i).at(ks...))` - not pretty but better than making a private public.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In language lawyer terms, `bar` is a name, to use it in the `decltype` expression the compiler has to do normal name lookup, which respects access control.
Why should `decltype` have been designed differently to the rest of the language? You haven't presented any convincing argument for why it shouldn't be consistent with e.g. `sizeof`.

As a class author, I don't want you to be able to query private implementation details like that.  If I wanted the type to be usable outside the class I'd define a public typedef telling you what type it is.

> and later on, I want another variable somewhere else that has the same type as `bar`

You want "another variable" that's the same type as a private implementation detail? So if the author of class `Foo` refactors their code and replaces the type with some other implementation detail, suddenly your code changes meaning and unrelated code might suddenly stop compiling or silently have different behaviour, because that code foolishly relied on private details that were none of its business.  That would introduce coupling between private implementation details and unrelated code that the author of `Foo` might not even know exists! That's a terrible idea.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. DO you have any references that assert this is the case please?

Comment: Assert what? That `bar` is a name and must be found by name lookup? How else will the compiler know what `Foo::bar` refers to in `decltype(Foo::bar)` if it doesn't do name lookup?

Comment: +1, also suggesting using `auto clone= foo.get_bar()` or `decltype(foo.get_bar()) clone` might help the user?

Comment: @JonathanWakely No I mean some docs that say that decltype doesn't work on privates for thie reason? I've not done C++ > 10 year and just heard about decltype.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I preferred it before you edited to say it was a terrible idea, and so on. I was never trying to argue that the language should be different. I was just asking why it was the way it is.

Usually, I just think of private as meaning that external functions can't access the data in that way - but that they can still know the data exists, because it's right there in the header file. But I see how it makes sense to think of private as having a stricter meaning.

Comment: @karadoc, the details are visible in the header, but that's a "necessary evil" due to how C++ works. _You_ can see the implementation details, by reading the code, but "external functions" can't use them or refer to them, and you should write code as though you don't know or care what those details are. (When C++ gets a proper modules system a class' private implementation details will be properly hidden.)

Comment: @PreetSangha, sounds like you need [docs on `decltype` itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype), which is new in C++11, not docs on why it can't access `private` data. It can't access private data for the same reason every other language feature can't access private data.

Comment: @JonathanWakely yeah - you're right - time for me to do some reading... what you're saying makes lots of sense - cheers!

Answer (score 14):

`decltype(Foo::bar)` **does** work inside `Foo`.

Outside `Foo`, you're not even supposed to *know* that `Foo` has a member named `bar` (that's what `private` means), so of course it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That is a gcc bug fixed in release 4.8.0:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52816

Comment: That bug is referring to something slightly different to what this question is about.