# Grouping items with specific attribute using STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have a multimap as such:
`multimap<float, obj*> mmap;`
Using multimap as some keys could be the same.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the multimap grouped/partitioned into separate groups based on some criteria. 
For instance, I want groups where the difference btw the float key is <= some threshold.

i.e. a multimap like this:
`<100, obj0*>, <99, obj1*>, <1000, obj2*>, <1001, obj3*>`
and I want to put them into groups where the difference btw the float key <= 1.

so the result should be:
`grp1: <100, obj0*>, <99, obj1*>`
`grp2: <1000, obj2*>, <1001, obj3*>`

I looked at std::transform, group_by etc but those don't seem to be the right approach. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do if you have keys like `98, 99, 100, 101`? The difference to the next is always `<=1`, but the difference from first to last is much bigger. Should that be one group? If not how would you want to partition it

Comment: Using a `float` as a key is really not a good idea. If you calculate this key it will most likely not work due to compounding rounding errors.

Comment: @Grizzly I was thinking the same thing, so you're not alone on this. I'm definitely curious, since that can potentially create 3 groups out of 4 items (and perhaps that is the intended behavior?).

Comment: I recently started writing my own `group_by` class to do this very kind of thing.  This post has a start:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14934749/975129 It uses recursive maps inside.  When you define your `group_by<>`, you can specify the KEYS you want to group by.  I have added some more functionality that's not posted to that link yet... (useful stuff like `apply()`, `members()`, `keys()`, `erase()` - all quite easy to write once that basic functionality is in place)

Comment: @grizzly: that's a good question.

Comment: You can divide the key by 2 and make it integer. In this case all keys, that differs by `1` will be in one basket

Comment: +1 @JoachimPileborg using float as a key is a v. bad idea

Comment: @grizzly: i guess they should all belong to a single group. I want to group items that have the same key or a key that is almost similar.

Comment: @borisbn - what you said works, in principle, but by having only two baskets, you effectively negate the usefulness of a map<> (you will have two big baskets of unsorted stuff).

Comment: OP, then you need to define a class, first, that can convert the float into the same (maybe uint) key for your definition of *almost similar*.  Then you use that class as a key.  You can even have a conversion operator to that class for convenience.  This class will almost be like a hash function:  the better it is able to distribute your domain (float) over the range evenly (maybe uint), the more effective it will be.

Comment: @kfmfe04: the floating point key has a range from 0.f to 1.f. I thought of mapping to unsigned char (as the range isn't very large) by multiplying with 255 but I'm not sure if that is a good approach.

Comment: @cks2k2 if you multiply by 255 and truncate, you will have up to 255 buckets.  That implies bucket widths of 1.0/255.0.  Now you can ask yourself, is that width roughly commiserate with your notion of *almost similar*?  If not, adjust your bucket width (or number of buckets) accordingly.  Also note that this bucketing will not be perfect due to alignment.  The more you optimise here, the less generic your algorithm may be (less chance for reuse), unless of course, you use templates.  That's also something to consider, if your project is large and may reuse this code in slightly different ways.